# Recuperar datos de un mapa en otra activity

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo una clase que se llama Maps, con la cual puedo conocer la ubicación del teléfono:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Button siguiente;
    TextView messageTextView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_services);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SelectServicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(siguiente);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        miUbicacion();
    }

    private void agregarMarcador(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);
        if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();
        marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(coordenadas)
                .draggable(true)
                .title("Mi posición actual")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
    }

    private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            agregarMarcador(lat, lng);

        }
    }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            actualizarUbicacion(location);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    private void miUbicacion() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            return;
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,15000,0,locationListener);

    }
}
```

[image: Así se visualiza la interfaz]

Sin embargo, sólo te muestra el marcador de tu posición, ¿cómo puedo obtener como tal la dirección del marcador y recuperarla en otro activity?

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que tengas la latitud y longitud deseada, debes utilizar un geocoder:

```
Geocoder mGeocoder = new Geocoder(context);
List<Address> lista = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);
```

Donde lista tendrá hasta 5 resultados (el último parámetro es el número de resultados que deseas). Los objetos Address dentro de la lista tienen calle, número, estado, etc. Puedes formar tus propias strings con esa información y pasarlas como extras a tu siguiente Activity, o hacer tus propios objetos parcelables para lograrlo.

Referencia: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html